# How do you access or SELECT Scale and Precision of a Data_Type?

Tags: sql, oracle, scale, precision

I am trying to print out a report from SQL Developer. When I SELECT the Data_Type I get the data type as expected, but I want the Scale and Precision also right beside it...for example

```
CHAR(3, 0)
NUMBER(7, 0)
```

Right now im only getting the data type itself like:

```
CHAR
NUMBER
```

What syntax am I missing to access or SELECT the Scale and Precision please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are "selecting" the data type, I assume you are "selecting" from something like `all_tab_columns`. Right? Like this:

```
select column_name, data_type
from   all_tab_columns
where  owner = 'SCOTT' and table_name = 'EMP'
;

COLUMN_NAME  DATA_TYPE   
------------ ------------
EMPNO        NUMBER      
ENAME        VARCHAR2    
JOB          VARCHAR2    
MGR          NUMBER      
HIREDATE     DATE        
SAL          NUMBER      
COMM         NUMBER      
DEPTNO       NUMBER
```

Now, you want to know the maximum length for `VARCHAR2` columns, and the precision and scale for `NUMBER`, right?

Add more columns to the `select`. Like so:

```
select column_name, data_type, char_col_decl_length, data_precision, data_scale
from   all_tab_columns
where  owner = 'SCOTT' and table_name = 'EMP'
;

COLUMN_NAME  DATA_TYPE    CHAR_COL_DECL_LENGTH DATA_PRECISION DATA_SCALE
------------ ------------ -------------------- -------------- ----------
EMPNO        NUMBER                                         4          0
ENAME        VARCHAR2                       10                          
JOB          VARCHAR2                        9                          
MGR          NUMBER                                         4          0
HIREDATE     DATE                                                       
SAL          NUMBER                                         7          2
COMM         NUMBER                                         7          2
DEPTNO       NUMBER                                         2          0
```

Alternatively, in SQL*Plus (or other interfaces that implement its functionality) you can use the SQL*Plus command `describe`:

```
describe scott.emp

Name     Null? Type         
-------- ----- ------------ 
EMPNO          NUMBER(4)    
ENAME          VARCHAR2(10) 
JOB            VARCHAR2(9)  
MGR            NUMBER(4)    
HIREDATE       DATE         
SAL            NUMBER(7,2)  
COMM           NUMBER(7,2)  
DEPTNO         NUMBER(2)
```

Very likely, SQL*Plus implements its own `describe` command with a `select` query just like the one I shared earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just describe the table using

```
   Desc tablename
```

Or

```
  Describe tablename
```

Comment: "desc" is not an sql command

Comment: Type the same in sqlplus command terminal n see the magic